# Julia JuMP Cbc solver hangs infinitely without message and without exiting

Tags: julia, julia-jump, coin-or-cbc, coin-or

I'm using Julia language (Version 1.3.1), JuMP package (Version 0.20.1) and Cbc package (Version 0.6.6) to solve an optimization problem in a docker container with ubuntu:16.04. The optimizer Cbc seems to be hung, with 100% cpu usage, without exiting and without any message. The problems happens rarely on similar problem and seems to be not replicable: if I run the same code with the same data it doesn't hang anymore. Hope that backtrace got through gdb can be useful.

I can share my model, if needed. It has 11520 variables, 4652 constraints, 10080 variables used in linear objective function.

This is the log of Cbc optimizer:

> Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver
> Version: 2.10.3  Build Date: Oct  7 2019
>
> command line - Cbc_C_Interface -threads 0 -seconds 360.0 -maxNodes 30000 -logLevel 1 -solve -quit (default strategy 1)  seconds was
> changed from 1e+100 to 360 maxNodes was changed from 2147483647 to
> 30000 Continuous objective value is 2.3607e+08 - 0.11 seconds
> Cgl0002I 3197 variables fixed Cgl0005I 7 SOS with 8323 members
> Cgl0004I processed model has 15 rows, 8323 columns (8323 integer (8323
> of which binary)) and 26556 elements  Cbc0045I Fixing only non-zero
> variables. Cbc0045I Warning: mipstart values could not be used to
> build a solution.

Here Cbc seems to be hung and becomes unresponsive, with 100% cpu usage.

Here the backtrace on the running pid process:

> #0  0x00007f163c3facc9 in ?? () from target:/root/.julia/packages/Cbc/vWzyC/deps/usr/lib/libCbcSolver.so
> #1  0x00007f163c4125b3 in ?? () from target:/root/.julia/packages/Cbc/vWzyC/deps/usr/lib/libCbcSolver.so
> #2  0x00007f163c467586 in ?? () from target:/root/.julia/packages/Cbc/vWzyC/deps/usr/lib/libCbcSolver.so
> #3  0x00007f163c46aebc in ?? () from target:/root/.julia/packages/Cbc/vWzyC/deps/usr/lib/libCbcSolver.so
> #4  0x00007f163c40594a in ?? () from target:/root/.julia/packages/Cbc/vWzyC/deps/usr/lib/libCbcSolver.so
> #5  0x00007f163c29afbe in ?? () from target:/root/.julia/packages/Cbc/vWzyC/deps/usr/lib/libCbcSolver.so
> #6  0x00007f163c2ad844 in ?? () from target:/root/.julia/packages/Cbc/vWzyC/deps/usr/lib/libCbcSolver.so
> #7  0x00007f163b8ea31f in CbcHeuristicDive::solution(double&, int&, int&, OsiRowCut**, CbcSubProblem**&, double*) () from
> target:/root/.julia/packages/Cbc/vWzyC/deps/usr/lib/libCbc.so.3
> #8  0x00007f163b8ebf42 in CbcHeuristicDive::solution(double&, double*) () from
> target:/root/.julia/packages/Cbc/vWzyC/deps/usr/lib/libCbc.so.3
> #9  0x00007f163b938fd2 in CbcModel::solveWithCuts(OsiCuts&, int, CbcNode*) () from
> target:/root/.julia/packages/Cbc/vWzyC/deps/usr/lib/libCbc.so.3
> #10 0x00007f163b9472d7 in CbcModel::branchAndBound(int) () from target:/root/.julia/packages/Cbc/vWzyC/deps/usr/lib/libCbc.so.3
> #11 0x00007f163c214c47 in CbcMain1(int, char const**, CbcModel&, int (*)(CbcModel*, int), CbcSolverUsefulData&) () from
> target:/root/.julia/packages/Cbc/vWzyC/deps/usr/lib/libCbcSolver.so
> #12 0x00007f163c2252ae in CbcMain1(int, char const**, CbcModel&) () from
> target:/root/.julia/packages/Cbc/vWzyC/deps/usr/lib/libCbcSolver.so
> #13 0x00007f163c19bc50 in Cbc_solve () from target:/root/.julia/packages/Cbc/vWzyC/deps/usr/lib/libCbcSolver.so
> #14 0x00007f16698e7e71 in ?? ()
> #15 0x000000000000000c in ?? ()
> #16 0x00007fff70694480 in ?? ()
> #17 0x00007f16604ce110 in ?? ()
> #18 0x000000000000262e in ?? ()
> #19 0x0000000000000006 in ?? ()
> #20 0x00007fff70694480 in ?? ()
> #21 0x00007f165966ab40 in ?? ()
> #22 0x00007f164a7ce1d0 in ?? ()
> #23 0x00007f164a7ce220 in ?? ()
> #24 0x00007f164a7ce1d0 in ?? ()
> #25 0x00007f1688be7b00 in ?? () at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/array.c:738 from
> target:/opt/julia/bin/../lib/libjulia.so.1
> #26 0x00007f163d909af0 in ?? ()
> #27 0x00007f164439d3c0 in ?? ()
> #28 0x00007f1689524200 in ?? ()
> #29 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Using `next` command in `gdb` console, than a StackOverflowError() error is catched on CbC.

Has the objective function too many terms?

Any help is really appreciable.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with Cbc. It's impossible to provide more advice without a reproducible example. I suggest you try to simplify your model and create an MPS file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Here the link where to find MPS file https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1_HD_Mozk8Lka42abrXQMKy8Pv-T7ko_4 (hope it's useful).

Comment: Is it better to update Cbc v 0.6.6 to Cbc v 0.7.0? Is it the last release but it's stable? Is there's a way to make a timeout on the function 'optimize!()' in order to deal with problem like this and force quit the optimizer? In which dimension do I have to simplify my model: variables, constraints or number of terms in objective function? Thank you so much in advance

Comment: When creating MPS file a warning appears:  'Warning: MathOptInterface.VariablePrimalStart() is not supported by MathOptFormat.MPS.InnerModel{Float64}. This information will be discarded.', so I think that in the MPS file the information about set_start_value is lost. I can share it.

Comment: After further investigations, could it be possible that Cbc solver to be hung on Heuristic? in the backtrace I've found 'CbcHeuristicDive' and very often in Cbc solver the line after Cbc0045I Warning: mipstart values could not be used to build a solution. is the one Cbc0012I Integer solution of 11300000 found by DiveCoefficient after 522 iterations and 0 nodes (0.25 seconds)

Comment: The drive link is not publicly accessible. Yes, you should update to 0.7. To set a time-limit, use `set_optimizer_attribute(model, "seconds", 100)`.

Comment: Now the link should be available, sorry for that. Ok, I'll update to Cbc v 0.7.0. I've already set a time limit of 360 seconds but the solver doesn't exit after that time when it hangs, like in my case. After further investigations, it seems to get stuck in the heuristic phase and for strange reason the time limit is not respected. Thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can set the time limit using the **seconds** parameter as follows.

For newer package versions:

```
model = Model(optimizer_with_attributes(Cbc.Optimizer
                                        ,"seconds" => 60
                                        ,"threads" => 4
                                        ,"loglevel" => 0
                                        ,"ratioGap" => 0.0001))
```

Or like this for older package versions:

```
model = Model(with_optimizer(Cbc.Optimizer
                             ,seconds=60
                             ,threads=4
                             ,loglevel=0
                             ,ratioGap=0.0001))
```